# Lodash/JS - Convert _.find statement to _.forEach

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm having trouble converting the following Lodash statement to something that works in an application that I inherited at work and am trying to fix bugs in. At the moment, we are having issues with only one device on our system returning when two devices have the same name and the following code seems to be the culprit as it would only return the first "true" value in an array:

```
var group = _.find(groupList, {id: id});
```

How would I successfully convert this to a statement that iterates over all objects in an array and then returns those objects? I've tried the following options to no avail:

```
 var group = _.filter(groupList, {id: id});
```

and

```
 var group = _.every(groupList, {id: id});
```

and

```
 var group = _.forEach(groupList, {id: id}) 
 return {id};
```

I know I am probably missing something in my syntax. Any help would be much appreciated. Running Lodash v3.7.0

Here's the rest of the code in the directive in case anyone is interested or sees something else I might be missing:

```
define(['./../_module'], function (directives) {
'use strict';
directives.directive('dmGroupedList', ['$compile', '$state', 'APP_CONSTANTS', function ($compile, $state, APP_CONSTANTS) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            groupBy: '=',
            actions: '=',
            nonameGroupLabel: '='
        },
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return attrs.templateUrl || 'views/shared-templates/grouped-list.html';
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watchGroup(['items', 'groupBy', 'nonameGroupLabel'], function () {
                scope.groupList = [];
                scope.groupedItems = {};

                var actions = scope.actions[scope.groupBy];

                _.forEach(scope.items, function (item) {
                    scope.handlers.getGroups(scope.groupList, item, scope.items, scope.groupBy, actions);
                });

                _.forEach(scope.groupList, function (group) {
                    var items = scope.groupedItems[group.id];
                    items = _.sortBy(items, function (item) {
                        return item.description;
                    });

                    scope.groupedItems[group.id] = items;
                });

                var groupsToSort = _.where(scope.groupList, {unassigned: false});
                var unassignedGroups = _.sortBy(_.where(scope.groupList, {unassigned: true}), 'name');
                scope.groupList = _.sortBy(groupsToSort, function (group) {
                    return group.name;
                });
                //adds unassigned groups to a new array via the javascript "push" method
                if (angular.isDefined(unassignedGroups)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < unassignedGroups.length; i++) {
                        scope.groupList.push(unassignedGroups[i]);
                    }
                }
            });

            scope.handlers = {
                getGroups: function (groupList, item, items, groupBy, actions) {
                    var group = item[groupBy];

                    if (_.isEmpty(group)) {
                        scope.handlers.addGroupToList(groupList, APP_CONSTANTS.DEVICE_NONE_NAME_MAPPING.NONE, items, groupBy, item, actions, scope);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (angular.isArray(group) || angular.isObject(group)) {
                            _.forEach(group, function (groupName) {
                                if (groupName == APP_CONSTANTS.ZERO) {
                                    scope.handlers.addGroupToList(groupList, APP_CONSTANTS.DEVICE_NONE_NAME_MAPPING.NONE, items, groupBy, item, actions, scope);
                                    return;
                                }

                                scope.handlers.addGroupToList(groupList, groupName, items, groupBy, item, actions, scope);
                            })
                        } else {
                            scope.handlers.addGroupToList(groupList, group, items, groupBy, item, actions, scope);
                        }
                    }
                },
                addGroupToList: function (groupList, groupId, items, groupBy, item, handlers, scope) {
                    var id = _.camelCase(groupId);

                   var group = _.find(groupList, {id: id});
                    //var group = _.forEach(groupList, {id: id})
                    //return {id};

                    if (!group) {
                        var name = '';
                        var unassigned = false;
                        var link = null;

                        if (groupId == APP_CONSTANTS.DEVICE_NONE_NAME_MAPPING.NONE || groupId == APP_CONSTANTS.DEVICE_NONE_NAME_MAPPING.NONE_PARENT_ID) {
                            if (groupId == APP_CONSTANTS.DEVICE_NONE_NAME_MAPPING.NONE_PARENT_ID) {
                                name = APP_CONSTANTS.DEVICE_NONE_NAME_MAPPING.NONE;
                            } else {
                                name = APP_CONSTANTS.DEVICE_NONE_NAME_MAPPING.UNASSIGNED;
                            }

                            unassigned = true;
                        } else {
                            link = handlers.getGroupLink(groupId);
                            name = handlers.getGroupName(groupId, items);
                        }

                        group = {id: id, name: name, unassigned: unassigned, link: link};

                        groupList.push(group);
                    }

                    scope.groupedItems[group.id] = scope.groupedItems[group.id] || [];

                    if (angular.isDefined(handlers.processingGroup)) {
                        handlers.processingGroup(group, groupList, groupId, items, groupBy, item, handlers, scope);
                    } else {
                        scope.groupedItems[group.id].push({
                            description: handlers.getItemDescription(item),
                            link: handlers.getItemLink(item)
                        })
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

});

Comment: If `var group = _.find(groupList, {id: id});` worked then `var group = _.filter(groupList, {id: id});` should work.

Comment: I think you should probably add which version of lodash you are using, there is major differences between v2, v3 and v4

Comment: v3.7.0 is the version

Comment: Ugh, that is quite a mess you've inherited. But yes, `scope.groupedItems[group.id] = scope.groupedItems[group.id] || [];` and other statements that reference `group.id` assume it is a single value. You have a lot of refactoring to do now...

Comment: I'm heading out for the day here. I will get back at it at 7am tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `filter`:

```
var group = groupList.filter((group) => group.id === id);
```

EDIT: to return only the element, and not an array, when there is only one match, you can do the following:

```
var checkSingle = (groups) => groups.length === 1 ? groups[0] : groups;
var group = checkSingle(groupList.filter((group) => group.id === id));
```

Comment: I tried this exact code but it broke the application. Do you know what the {id: id} would represent in the above code? Application running in AngularJS also if that helps. Again, I didn't create the original code

Comment: @SDH also consider that the initial `.find()` returns a _single_ value, and this returns an _array_. The suggestion itself is probably not what's breaking the application, but other parts of the code assuming `group` is a single group with the `id`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I added the full code for the directive above if you want to check it out. It's totally possible that I might have missed something

Answer (score 0):

You can `_(groupList).groupBy('id').get(id)`:

```js
var groupList = [
  { id: 1, name: 'site' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test' },
  { id: 2, name: 'prod' },
  { id: 3, name: 'dev' },
  { id: 4, name: 'back' },
  { id: 4, name: 'front' },
  { id: 5, name: 'sprint' }
];

console.log(_(groupList).groupBy('id').get(2));
console.log(_(groupList).groupBy('id').get(3));
console.log(_(groupList).groupBy('id').get(4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```